# How can I get the index of the changed selection?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple selections with the same id and name, and I am wondering how I can get the index of the changed selection, **NOT** the index of the selected element/option of this selection.

Here is my attempt:

```
$("select").change(function ()
{
    var index = $(this).index();
    checkTypes(index);
})
```

It's alwas returning index 0.

My view (in for loop)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Columns[i].Type, new SelectList(Model.Columns[i].Types), new { @ID = "Typeselection", @class = "form-control", @style="width:150px;" })
```

Which generates following HTML:

```
<select id="Typeselection" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Typ&quot; ist erforderlich." name="Columns[0].Type" style="width:150px;">
<option selected="selected">BigInt</option>
<option>Binary</option>
<option>Bit</option>
</select>
<select id="Typeselection" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Typ&quot; ist erforderlich." name="Columns[1].Type" style="width:150px;">
<option>BigInt</option>
<option>Binary</option>
<option>Bit</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML ?

Comment: @Zenoo I added my html, but I don't think it will help that much :D

Comment: `index()` only works for siblings. If the elements are not siblings then you need to provide a selector to `index()` to match them within

Comment: @Liam yes i know, but I generate the selection by code. I don't think it's the beautiful way if i just add the index to the id/name?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can i achieve this? :D I started working with jQuery today :/

Comment: Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say

Comment: @DavidWalser: Add the generated HTML, because your code would work if the HTML would be like `<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>`. Without it, no one is gonna give you an answer...

Comment: i think you need to assign unique id to each selection , as you are creating the selections inside a loop you can concatenate  the iterator with the selection Id like 
  new { @ID = "Typeselection_""+i+""" })

Comment: @umer but I don't think that's the best way. that's why I am asking here :)

Comment: @JacobvanLingen As desrcibed above, I have **MULTIPLE** selections, not options..

Comment: David , then you can add a data attribute like data-index=i to each selection and get this attribute value inside onchange event handler .

Comment: sorry for not providing my html at the beginning :/

Comment: You sorted it in the end that's the important thing. You can save yourself a lot of hassle by always providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem, [adding the right tags and not putting tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `<select>`s aren't siblings, your code won't work.

To make it work without them being siblings, you'll have to loop through your initial selector `$('select')` and check for each element one by one with jQuery `.is()` method:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  let that = this;  // that = the <select> that changed
  let index;

  $('select').each(function(i) { // Loop through all your <select>s
    if ($(this).is($(that))) index = i; // Store the right one's index
  });
  
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="Typeselection" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Typ&quot; ist erforderlich." name="Columns[0].Type" style="width:150px;">
    <option selected="selected">BigInt</option>
    <option>Binary</option>
    <option>Bit</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="Typeselection" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;Typ&quot; ist erforderlich." name="Columns[1].Type" style="width:150px;">
    <option>BigInt</option>
    <option>Binary</option>
    <option>Bit</option>
  </select>
</div>
```